facing error: no module pycaret.utils.generic while executing pycaret.classification import *
PyCaret is having lots of issue. python 3.8 support PyCaret versions. I am using PyCaret 2.3.6.
It is compatible with numpy version lesser than 1.20 . I am using PyCaret 2.3.6. and Numpy 1.19.5 in python 3.8 env. Still I am facing error: no module pycaret.utils.generic while executing
pycaret.classification import *.
Tried all PyCaret and Numpy version still facing error:
no module pycaret.utils.generic while executing 
pycaret.classification import *


i am running it in gcp #google cloud

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
